# Problems deleting invoiceid on update with plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I’m trying to create a plugin that delete each **InvoiceDetail** on an **Update** state and **Synchronous** mode (because Asyncronous also dont work),
so, I try to just get the **InvoiceDetailId** of each **InvoiceDetail** when updated and then delete it

First:

```
// get the invoicedetailid  
var The_Guid_InvoiceDetail_ID = entity.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("invoicedetailid");
```

and then

```
// just delet it
service.Delete("invoicedetail", The_Guid_InvoiceDetail_ID);
```

In theory, if I´m on an order, with several **OrderDetails**, and i click on *"Create Invoice"*, each new **InvoiceDetail** shoud be deleted automaticly and my new invoice will be without any **InvoiceDetail**

but i get an error that sais

> InvoiceDetail With Id = 3851d9d4-5e4c-e811-80fe-3863bb35fc90
>   Does Not Exist

this just happend if i have more than one order detail, if i just have one, it is deleted

please, help!!

My code:

```
namespace My_Cool_Plugin
{
    public class Class1 : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = (IOrganizationService)factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
            ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));


            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {
                Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                var The_Guid_InvoiceDetail_ID = entity.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("invoicedetailid");

                service.Delete("invoicedetail", The_Guid_InvoiceDetail_ID);

            } // if context end
        } // Execute end
    } // class Class1 end
} // namespace end
```

Comment: Did you verify those records where it says does not exists? you can open an existing record, then replace the guid from error in url & see, they may not be in database..

Comment: Doing a delete of a record in the plugin pipeline handling the update of the same record may be considered as a hack. It may work in some cases, but I would not count on that. In your case the deletion of an invoicedetail record may invoke an update of the remaining invoicedetail records, thus deleting them. I am just guessing, but maybe it's worth looking for that kind of side effects.

Comment: Thanks
Im also guessing that, becaus im deleting this record whild its been updated, at the end of the process, the system try to save it but because it doesn't exist anymore, it crash